# Python writing a string to an maximum of one line in a textile

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, text, read-write

I have a dataframe, which can be downloaded [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/399c75e9875057182fcaa60061ebc48220180621093031/31369b). The first column contains a question while the second column contains an answers to that question.

**My aim:** To create two .txt files, one that contains questions and one that contains answers.

Each questions and answer should be written on a individual row. So that Row 50 in each .txt file contains the 50th question and the 50th answer. (IE that if the files are recombined the questions/answer pairs match up)

The code snippet below opens a textfile, writes each row of the column to that file and removes any \n. It seems to work for about 96% of the rows, but very rarely it writes a single DF row across multiple text lines.

These rare events don't seem to have any defining characteristics, they are not extremely long etc. For the file I attached above, the first one occurs at text file line 395 in the answers column.

```
f = open("Answers.txt","a", newline="\n",encoding='utf-8')
for i in tqdm(data['answers_body']):
        line =  i.replace('\n','')
        f.write(line)
        f.write("\n")
```

Interestingly, if I remove the f.write and just print to the console it seems to be work as expected... the issue only occurs during the write process.

Comment: It is because it read the line but you have to add the newline in the file so it writes on the new line better go `file.write(line+'\n')`

Comment: It's already doing that with the second "f.write("\n")" right? I tried your suggestion and the issue is still occuring.

Comment: Provide a couple of lines from the file here, including the offending line in your sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: full version that resulting 1001 lines

```
import csv

data = []
with open('SO_dataset.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in spamreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
        data.append((row[2] if len(row)> 2 else ''))

f = open("Answers.txt", "w")
i = 0
for line in data:
    i += 1
    line =  line.replace('\n',' ')
    f.write(str(i) + '. ' + line)
    f.write("\n")
f.close
```

Actually, your original code seems fine. If you are talking about the txt file break your line and wrap to next line, that's property of Notepad... If you input them into word or excel, they should be fine without breaking line.

Comment: Is that in addition to the replace('\n','')  or instead of?

Comment: In addition, I once before handled this situation, sometime double quote may counted as nextline. Not just quotes,  even comma maybe. Take a look on https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/working-with-text-files

Comment: So it should be line.replace('\n','') then line.replace('"','\\"'). Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be helping...

Comment: @F.D I make a full ver that work, you have 1001 lines in data, while the result has 1001 lines too.

Answer (score -1):

It is because it reads the line, and that's why it prints the line but when you write to the file it is writing on the same line, 
you have to add the newline to the line  so the next line jumps on a new line 
For simplicity you can go  `file.write(line+'\n')`

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use print(line, file=f) instead, may the optional seperator is set to end="some sign" if you want...

**EDIT**
Sorry for writing such complicated: Also print has the ability to "write" into files. It also offers an option for alternative ending see above - For your case it would be:

```
    f = open("Answers.txt","a", newline="\n",encoding='utf-8')
    for i in tqdm(data['answers_body']):
        line =  i.replace('\n','')
        print(line, file=f)
    f.close()
```

if wanted or needed for other cases with print(line, file=f, end='\t') instead of a newline a tab is the last sign and the next print() continues after the tab

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting here.. can you expand on it please using the code example above?

Comment: Thanks for the edit and interesting approach! Still not fixing the problem. Ps f.close() should be added to the end